# PHP/Wordpress Display the user search query inside of a search input

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom index.php page and would like to make the users search result save inside of a search box. Here was what I peiced together that works a little bit:

```
<li class="result-searh"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://droogle.dil/">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value=<?php printf( esc_html__( '%s', stackstar ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?> name="s" id="s">
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
                </div>
            </form></li>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: my searcg]

When I search for "my search". As you can see, its is showing up. Just a bit funny looking. I am quite terrible at PHP so forgive me if this looks bad. I Frankenstein'd this code together using other plugins' code.

-

EDIT: changed it to this:

```
<input type="text" value=<?php printf( esc_html__( '%s', stackstar ), get_search_query()); ?> name="s" id="s">
```

and now when I search for "Hello I am joe" inspecting the element gives me this:

```
<input type="text" value="hello" I="" am="" joe="" name="s" id="s">
```

Answer (score 1):

Going out on an untested limb and proposing enclosing the `<php .. ?>` with double quotes might fix this:

`<input type="text" value="<?php printf( esc_html__( '%s', stackstar ), get_search_query()); ?>" name="s" id="s">`

Comment: sadly I tried that and it just fills the box with the code